# pandas could not be resolved from source jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to get Python3, Pandas, Jupyter, virtual envs working on one of my remote machines, via Visual Studio Code.

I don't fully understand how all the moving parts interact, yet.

When one of my test Jupyter Notebooks is open, although I can run the Python 3 code without issue, Visual Studio Code shows a warning `Import "pandas" could not be resolved from sourcePylance`.

Further to this, there appears to be something missing from the Status Bar. Elsewhere I have seen descriptions of a widget on the status bar which relates to Python development. I think it is for switching Python environments, or similar. I have installed the Python Extension Pack. I don't know why this doesn't show up. This suggests to me that I haven't got something setup quite right.

I searched for a solution to the "import Pandas could not be resolved" issue and saw suggestions to run `pip3 install pandas`. If I try and do this, I see the following message:

```
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.

    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.

    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.

    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

My system is Debian 12. A recent change prevents pip installing any packages without first creating a virtual environment. (At least by default.) This is to prevent conflicts with system packages.

This is why I opted to create a venv in the folder I am currently working in. However, taking this route appears to prevent the Python syntax analysis extensions from working when working inside a Jupyter Notebook.

How should I setup my system to fix this?

Note: Although VS Code as shown in the screenshot is running on a Windows machine, it is connected to a development server running Debian 12.

The code in the Notebook does run, suggesting the issue is not with the Jupyter configuration, but something else.

[image: VS Code]

Comment: maybe the `Select kernel` on the top right of VSCode?

Comment: 1. Ctrl + Shift + P -> Interpreter.


2. Navigate to your `./.venv/bin/` & Select `python`

3. Click on "Select Kernel" from top right in jupyter window and select the same interpreter.

4. Open a **new** shell and type `Which python` (Linux) or `Where Python` (Windows).

5. Make sure that the path it shows is the same as the one in your `.venv`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. When clicking "Select Kernel" I get a choice between "Python Environments", "Jupyter Kernel" and "Existing Jupyter Server". What is the difference between these? Can ask as a seperate question if necessary.